# Flask local live feed website with Python and SocketIO

Tags: python, html, flask, socket.io, localhost

I want to set up a simple locally hosted website. The backend code is supposed to fetch data from a website (in my simple case, memes from Reddit), store them on my machine and then upload them on my locally hosted website periodically. To get the live feed experience, I used the SocketIO package. So far, everything is working just fine, just that the images are not showing up on the website.

I have these files:

meme_fetcher.py:

```
import praw
import schedule
import time
from threading import Thread
from config import REDDIT_USER_AGENT, REDDIT_CLIENT_ID, REDDIT_CLIENT_SECRET, REDDIT_USERNAME, REDDIT_PASSWORD
import os
import shutil
import requests

# Define a list to store fetched memes
memes = []

def create_reddit_client():
    return praw.Reddit(
        user_agent=REDDIT_USER_AGENT,
        client_id=REDDIT_CLIENT_ID,
        client_secret=REDDIT_CLIENT_SECRET,
        username=REDDIT_USERNAME,
        password=REDDIT_PASSWORD
    )

def extract_image_url(url):
    # Extracting the image URL from the Reddit submission URL
    return url.split("?")[0]

def fetch_memes(subreddit_name, limit=10):
    reddit = create_reddit_client()
    new_memes = []

    subreddit = reddit.subreddit(subreddit_name)
    for submission in subreddit.rising(limit=limit):
        if not submission.is_self:  # Exclude text posts
            meme_data = {
                'title': submission.title,
                'image_url': extract_image_url(submission.url),
                'author': submission.author.name if submission.author else "Unknown",
                'upvotes': submission.score,
                'downvotes': submission.downs,
            }
            new_memes.append(meme_data)

    if not os.path.exists('imgs'):
        os.makedirs('imgs')
    else:
        shutil.rmtree('imgs')  # Clear the 'imgs' directory before storing new images
        os.makedirs('imgs')

    for i, meme in enumerate(new_memes):
        image_data = requests.get(meme['image_url'], stream=True)
        image_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'imgs', f"meme_{i}.jpg") # Change to the appropriate path of the 'imgs' directory
        with open(image_path, 'wb') as handler:
            handler.write(image_data.content)
        meme['image_url'] = f"imgs/meme_{i}.jpg"
        print(f"Updated image_url for meme {i}: {meme['image_url']}")

    return new_memes

# Start a thread to execute scheduled tasks
def run_scheduler():
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Start the scheduler thread
    scheduler_thread = Thread(target=run_scheduler)
    scheduler_thread.start()
```

app.py:

```
import eventlet
import eventlet.wsgi
from flask import Flask, render_template, send_from_directory
from flask_socketio import SocketIO
from meme_fetcher import fetch_memes, memes
import schedule
import threading
import time
import os
import logging

app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='/imgs', static_folder='imgs')
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@app.route('/live_feed', methods=['GET'])
def live_feed():
    logging.info("live feed: successful!")
    return render_template('index.html')

# Serve static files from the 'imgs' directory
@app.route('/imgs/<path:filename>')
def serve_image(filename):
    logging.info(f"Requested image: {filename}")
    return send_from_directory('imgs', filename)


# Function to fetch new memes periodically and update the memes list
def fetch_new_memes_periodically():
    global memes
    subreddit_name = 'memes'  # Change to your desired subreddit
    limit = 10  # Change the limit as needed
    new_memes = fetch_memes(subreddit_name, limit)
    memes.extend(new_memes)
    modified_memes = [{'title': meme['title'], 'image_url': meme['image_url'], 'author': meme['author'], 'upvotes': meme['upvotes'], 'downvotes': meme['downvotes']} for meme in new_memes]  # Modify the image URL appropriately
    #print("modified_memes")
    #print(modified_memes)
    socketio.emit('new_meme', {'memes': modified_memes[-10:]}, namespace='/live_feed')

# Schedule the fetch_new_memes_periodically function to run every 5 minutes
schedule.every(5).minutes.do(fetch_new_memes_periodically)

# Start a thread to execute scheduled tasks
def run_scheduler():
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Starting the scheduler thread...")
    scheduler_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_scheduler)
    scheduler_thread.start()
    print("Server is running...")
    eventlet.wsgi.server(eventlet.listen(('127.0.0.1', 5000)), app)
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Live Feed</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Welcome to the Live Feed!</h1>

    <div id="memes-container">
        <!-- Memes will be displayed here -->
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/4.0.0/socket.io.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        const socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + '/live_feed');

        socket.on('connect', function () {
            console.log('Connected to the server!');
        });

        socket.on('new_meme', function (data) {
            const memes = data.memes;
            const memesContainer = document.getElementById('memes-container');

            memes.forEach(function (meme) {
                const memeElement = document.createElement('div');
                memeElement.innerHTML = `
                    <div>
                        <h3>${meme.title}</h3>
                        <p>Author: ${meme.author}</p>
                        <p>Upvotes: ${meme.upvotes}</p>
                        <p>Downvotes: ${meme.downvotes}</p>
                        <img src="${meme.image_url}" alt="${meme.title}" style="max-width: 400px;">
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                `;
                memesContainer.appendChild(memeElement);
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Folder structure:

- project_folder/
- |-- app.py                  # Main application script
- |-- templates/              # HTML templates folder
- |   |-- index.html          # Template for rendering memes
- |-- config.py               # Configuration file settings
- |-- imgs/
- |   |-- image files

I already revised multiple points:

- The server is set up properly
- The images are downloaded, named and stored as intended
- The defined paths look fine to me

However, still on the website, only the main title shows up but nothing else.

I think, the problem is in the `index.html` file and the communication between the script and the app route functions.

Maybe someone has an idea what I am doing wrong here? I am new to the HTML-Python type of projects and would appreciate any type of help!

Thanks!

Comment: Your javascript code expects the `new_meme` message to come from the server. I don't see any code for `connect` handlers attached. Did you try to debug the websocket connection on the javascript side and see whether you successfully connect to the server and get the messages from it?